# Error while signing .apk file through jarsigner

Tags: android

I have tried to sign the .apk file using jarsigner by a command  :-

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin> jarsigner -keystore "C:\Program
>   Files.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
>   "C:\Program Files.android\AndroidCalculator.apk" androiddebugkey

Also, I have zipalign it by a command :-

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin> zipalign 4 "C:\Program
>   Files.android\Andr oidCalculator.apk" "C:\Program
>   Files.android\Calculator.apk"

But when I try to install it using adb install command :-

> C:\Program Files\android-sdks\platform-tools> adb install "C:\Program
>   Files.andr oid\Calculator.apk"

I get an error like -

> C:\Program Files\android-sdks\platform-tools>adb install "C:\Program
>   Files.android\Calculator.apk" 258 KB/s (16409 bytes in 0.062s)
>           pkg: /data/local/tmp/Calculator.apk Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]

**Note:** debug.keystore is store in `C:\Program Files\.android\`

I have also done with

> - jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore    my-release-key.keystore AndroidCalculator.apk CALCULATOR

but it ask me ENTER PASSPHRASE. I enter "android" but nothing happened, it shows me error

Answer (score 0):

Create you own new certificate for which you will provide the passphrase and then use that certificate. on Asking PASSPHRASE - supply the one you set while creating it.

Answer (score 0):

Eclips Step To create keystore or bla bla blah

```
-->right click on project
-->Select Export 
-->Next to project which you want to create sign
-->checked create new keystore
-->Select the path and name 
-->fill the Password
-->Give a Alias name
-->Give Password
-->35 year Above Certificate Expire date
-->Give Next 
-->Give Apk Name
-->Finished
```